# Connection between conic sections and matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

On [this MIT lecture](https://youtu.be/SreJp2U0Vio?t=1951) the presenter makes an interesting connection between conic sections and linear algebra:

> You remember the Greeks, they had these **conic sections**. They had ellipses, they had parabolas, the marginal case, and then they had hyperbolas. And they all come from **second degree things**. If I have a

$$ax^2 + 2bxy+ c y^2 = 1$$

> that's one of those curves. And if it was $x^2 + y^2=1,$ it was a circle. If it was $x^2 + 7y^2=1,$ it would be an ellipse. The **positive definite**-- It all comes down to linear algebra, of course. If that little matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\b&c
\end{bmatrix}$$

> is positive definite, so that means $a$ and $c$ are positive, and $ac$ is bigger than $b^2,$ you know the test for positive definite. What kind of curve do the Greeks have? What kind of equipotential-- What kind of a curve have we got here? An ellipse. If this curve, if that little matrix is indefinite, as, for example, here $\big [2xy =1  \big ].$ So with this one, what would be the matrix, what's the matrix that goes with $2xy,$ if I match this with this.
>   That's the matrix: $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$ There's no $a^2,$ there's no $x^2,$ there's no $y^2.$ And there are $2xy$'s, I think the matrix is that. So it's this nice symmetric matrix. Is that a positive definite matrix Certainly not. It's indefinite. It's eigenvalues are plus one and minus one, adding to the trace zero. So indefinite matrices correspond to hyperbolas. And later on, definite matrices will correspond to elliptic partial differential equations. And indefinite matrices-- Like Laplace. And indefinite matrices will correspond to hyperbolic partial differential equations, like the wave equation. What's the-- Now we're here. I didn't expect to get here. What's the marginal case? What's the marginal case between positive definite and indefinite is...? Semidefinite. Great. And what kind of a curve do you think comes when this little matrix is semidefinite. It's the one in between ellipses and hyperbolas. The marginal guy is a parabola. Right. So semidefinite would correspond to a parabola.

Can I get an explanation as to how these matrices are built and used, as well as their geometric interpretation to match them with conic sections?

Comment: The $a,b,c$ in the displayed matrix are the same as the $a,b,c$ in the displayed equation. That's how the matrix is built.

Comment: And the equation is simply $z^TAz=1$ where $z=[x\ y]^T$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Matrix_notation

Comment: There is a book Linear Algebra Through Geometry by Thomas Banchoff and John  Wermer. Your question is explained in 2, 3 and multi demantional vectors space